# Formatar diferença entre duas datas

Tags: python, datetime

Calculei o período entre duas datas no formato `d H : M : S`, e agora estou tentando formatá-lo, mas ainda não consegui, segue um exemplo de entrada e saída do que desejo, e meu código:

```
ENTRADA

Dia 5
08 : 12 : 23
Dia 9
06 : 13 : 23

SAÍDA

3 dia(s)
22 hora(s)
1 minuto(s)
0 segundo(s)
```

```py
from datetime import datetime

Di = str(input())
Hi = str(input())
Df = str(input())
Hf = str(input())

inicio = f'{Di[4:]} {Hi}'
fim = f'{Df[4:]} {Hf}'
f = '%d %H : %M : %S'
dif = (datetime.strptime(fim, f) - datetime.strptime(inicio, f))
dif = datetime.strftime(dif, "%d dia(s)\n"
                             "%H hora(s)\n"
                             "%M minuto (s)\n"
                             "%S segundo(s)")

print(dif)
```

Tentei fazer a formatação na linha 12 a 15. Gostaria que, se possível, preservasse o resto da lógica do meu código, que modificasse apenas o que realmente fosse necessário para resolver o problema.

Comment: Só um detalhe, `input` já retorna uma string então fazer `str(input())` é desnecessário. Faça apenas `input()` que é suficiente

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, existem dois conceitos importantes que você deve saber para entender como resolver o seu problema: "horários" e "durações". Para entender melhor, considere as duas frases abaixo:

- o filme começa às duas horas da tarde
- o filme tem duração de duas horas

No primeiro caso, "duas horas" refere-se a um horário: a um momento específico do dia.

No segundo caso, "duas horas" refere-se a uma duração: a uma quantidade de tempo. Nesse caso, ela não diz quando o filme começa ou termina (nem se ele foi de fato exibido). Ela só diz a duração (quanto tempo ele dura), sem qualquer relação com algum horário específico.

O problema é que usamos as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, etc) para ambos, mas eles são conceitos diferentes. Para piorar, até mesmo a forma de escrever pode ser igual: por exemplo, muitos cronômetros mostram "02:00" para indicar uma duração de duas horas, igual a um relógio.

Apesar de diferentes, estes conceitos estão relacionados. Se você somar uma data e uma duração, o resultado é outra data (se eu sei o horário que algo começa e quanto tempo dura, consigo calcular a hora que termina).

Em Python, uma duração é representada por [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), enquanto datas e horas são representadas por [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

No caso, ao subtrair uma data de outra, o resultado é um `timedelta`.
Infelizmente a API atual só permite formatação de datas (não é possível usar `strftime` com um `timedelta`), e para durações você tem que fazer manualmente:

```
# ... ler dados, etc (igual ao seu código)

# diferença entre datas, "dif" será um timedelta
dif = datetime.strptime(fim, f) - datetime.strptime(inicio, f)

# obter o total de segudos
secs = int(dif.total_seconds())

# calcular o equivalente em dias, horas e minutos
dias, secs = divmod(secs, 24 * 3600)
horas, secs = divmod(secs, 3600)
minutos, secs = divmod(secs, 60)

print(f'{dias} dia(s)\n{horas} hora(s)\n{minutos} minuto(s)\n{secs} segundo(s)')
```

A ideia é usar `total_seconds` para obter a duração total em segundos, e depois fazer alguns cálculos para saber quantos dias, horas e minutos tem esta duração (para isso eu uso [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), que já retorna ao mesmo tempo o resultado da divisão e o resto da mesma).